# How Can I Avoid the Following Error Message: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" When Inserting a Record into an MS Access Table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Microsoft Access 2007. After running the sub below I get the following error message: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" Despite this error message, the record is inserted into the appropriate table. Can someone explain what may be causing this error?

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

On Error GoTo HandleError

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

SQL = "INSERT INTO [Hiring Entity]  ([Hiring Entity]) VALUES (""RICH PC2"");"

rs.Open SQL, CurrentProject.Connection, _
      adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

With rs
    .AddNew
End With

   Set rs = Nothing
       rs.Close

ExitHere:

    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an object that does not exist.

Change this:

```
Set rs = Nothing
rs.Close
```

to this:

```
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

You were trying to close the object after it was gone.

Answer (score 1):

@Pow-lan explained the error occurred because you set `rs` to `Nothing` before attempting `rs.Close`.  The `.Close` method is not available for a recordset object variable after you set it to `Nothing`.

However, I'm left wondering why you use a recordset at all.  Your `SQL` string contains an `INSERT` statement.  So if the point is to add a row, just execute the `INSERT` statement.  No recordset required.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute SQL
```

Actually, you don't even need ADO (`CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`) to execute that query.  DAO should be fine.

```
CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
```